# How to count how many times values were used in the array C?

Tags: c, arrays, count

Here's my problem

If certain number has been entered into an array I need that number to be displayed and occurrence of that number in the array.

for example if user enters number 5 three times then "The number 5 has been entered 3 times so far" and so on

Here's my code so far:

```
int i,j;
int num_count = 0;

for(i=0;i<6;i++) {
    num_count = 0;
    for(j=1;j<43;j++) {
        if( *(num + i) == j) {
            printf("The number %d has been used %d times\n",j,num_count);
        }//end if
    }//end inner for
}//end outer for
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to create a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) of your data. You have to decide what data structure you want to use for the histogram depending on the range of values that can be stored in your array. If there is just a small number of possible values, use an array. If the value could be anything, you need something more flexible.

Comment: `*(num + i)` is normally written as `num[i]`.  Also, `num_count` is only ever set to `0`, so I'm not sure why printing its value in the inner loop is of much interest.

Comment: Do you realize that your maximum value is the answer to the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything?

Answer (score 1):

I will like to suggest you a very time efficient method for this, but it needs some extra memory.

Assume the upper limit of numbers inside array is 'MAX_NUM_IN_ARRAY',
so you should create array (say counter) of size 'MAX_NUM_IN_ARRAY+1' and initialize it to 0.

```
int counter[MAX_NUM_IN_ARRAY+1]={0};
```

now scan the input array from first to last element,
for each number:
    //say number is **num**
    counter[num]++;

and at the end you have to just scan that counter array from index 1 to MAX_NUM_IN_ARRAY.

Sample code:

Suppose input array is a[],
number of elements in array is n,
maximum limit of number inside array is MAX_LIMIT

```
int counter[MAX_LIMIT]={0};
int i;

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
   counter[a[i]]++;
}

for(i=0; i<MAX_LIMIT; i++)
{
    printf("Number %d is appeared for %d times\n", i, counter[i]);
}
```

Comment: I would like to save the result and store the value if user enters number again so for example: user enters 5 and 3 (number 5 appeared 1 times) then user enters number 5 again (number 5 appeared 2 times) and so on thanks @Bhavesh Munot

Comment: This histogram approach allows you to incrementally update the numbers.  If the user overwrites an element of the array, simply decrement the counter associated with the old value and increment the counter associated with the new value.

Answer (score -1):

============EDIT

You could write a series of functions that handle your collection. the collection could be a 2 dimentional array like so `numbers[][]` where numbers[n][0] is your number, and numbers[n][1] is the number of times it occurred...  and the gold would be in your add() function

add() does a few things, a user passes a value to add(),

first checks if number exists in numbers[n][0]

if the value exists at numbers[n][0]

```
numbers[n][1]++;
```

if it doesn't already exist,

check if the array is full

if it is full, copy all the data to a new, larger array

add it to the end of the array.. this is how to do it.

==OR

just design a 1 dimentional array `numbers[]` that holds all of your numbers.. and the add() function only:

if(it is full){copies to larger array}

adds number to the end;

and modify the code I wrote earlier (Below).. to print the most common number and it's occurrence count

============EDIT

I'm a Java guy so you'll need to translate (shouldn't be too hard..)

This is going to be just like a sorting algorithm with a little bit of extra logic (later search for Selection Sort)

```
int[] temp = {4,3,2,4,4,5};

////// find the most commonly occuring value

int times;
int moreTimes = 1;

int value = temp[0];

for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {

  times = 1;

  for(int j = i+1; j < temp.length; j++) {

    if(temp[i] == temp[j])
      times++;

  }

  if(times > moreTimes) {

    moreTimes = times;
    value = temp[i];

  }

}

/////// count the most common value

int count = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {

  if(temp[i] == value)
    count++;

}

System.out.println("number: " + value + ", count: " + count);
```

Comment: try to split it up into proper functions and make sure you check that the array has at least one value

Comment: Do you know how to save the values so every time user enters new set of numbers it counts as the number has been used again?

Comment: I think I have a solution... check my edit @user3421495